# Howto disable/enable the "receiver/stream/publisher/execution plan"

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-cep

Can we disable/enable the "receiver/stream/publisher/execution plan" in Management Console ? We only see they have "delete" action link, and how we can just disable them instead of delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid currently there's is no such way to disable the execution plan. But the feature is in the road map and will be available in future releases.